# Does the fragmental Atman travels?

Tags: atma, advaita, rebirth, jiva

Shankara in one of his verses gives the definition of jiva -""When the omnipresent Atman is limited or embodied by the mind,ego of subtle body, it is called jiva"". 
I think what he means is, once the omnipresent atman is embodied by the subtle body, it becomes a fragment called jiva. {{Fragmental Atman = jiva}}.

A question seems to be troubling me for quite some time now. Advaitians believe that Atman is  omnipresent and therefore  doesn't travel after death. Only the subtle body does the travelling. But what about the fragmental embodied atman known as jiva, does that travel along with the subtle body?

Comment: Yes. It travels

Comment: Which scripture says that?

Comment: It would be better if you provide information in which of his work has Adi Shankara given that definition of Jiva.

Comment: It was an ebook i found on the web.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing happens after death to the atman which is merely a witness. It is the subtle body that is affected by death. Check Gita 2.17-2.22 for the answer to your question. For example, Gita 2.22 says,

> 'Just as a man gives up old garments and puts on new ones, so the
>   embodied self abandons decrepit bodies and assumes new ones.'

*Gita 2.22*

What happens immediately after death? The answer is given in Gita 15.8 which says,

> When he gets a new body or abandons an old one, **the Jiva, the lord of
>   the body, moves, carrying them (the mind and the senses) with him, as
>   the wind carries smells from their seats (in flowers and the like).**

*Gita 15.8*

What this means is that the physical body dies but the mind and the senses of the jiva leave the physical body.Persons who have not attained moksha are part of the life-death-life.... cycle. They may also have to stay in heaven or hell for some time if they have done a particularly good thing or a heinous crime, respectively. After the merit of their particular good karma or the demerit of their particular bad karma is exhausted, they will again be born into the Earth plane.

Comment: Hello, are you sure that nothing happens to the atman. A group of advaitians hold on to the belief that it gets embodied or trapped inside our material bodies. Like air would get trapped in a jar. So if it actually gets embodied then it eventually becomes a fragment. Isn't it?

Comment: The next thing is, what is jiva? If its the embodied atman trapped or limited in subtle body, as Shankara says, then it too must travel along with subtle body. The gita verses above aren't clear whether jiva is the embodied fragmental atman or is it the subtle body. In some verses of the Gita, words like Naraha, Purusha, Dehi are also used which makes things more confusing.

Comment: Atman means consciousness in Advaita Vedanta. It is not like air trapped in a jar. So Atman trapped in a body simply means body is conscious. So some kind of consciousness is there in the subtle body even after the death of the physical body.

Comment: Allright. So this consciousness which is present in the subtle body, if its not trapped or embodied, in other words, if its not an unique alotted portion of consciousness given to each subtle body, then the avaccheda vada people used the word 'embodied' as a metaphor??

Comment: If that is the case, i can only picture the subtle body travelling within the infinite feild of atman and is made conscious due to being pervaded by atman. Just like a plastic immersed in water, gets wet but never traps water, the same way the subtle body never traps atman. I hope im right.

Comment: @greglevenski As per Gruda purana, when one dies then Atma leaves that body and enters in sukshma Shareer which is equal to size of our thumb. When atma is inside that sukshma shareer then it's called "Jeevatma". It's jeevatma who goes to hell/heaven to experience grief/joy, not atma.

Comment: @Rishabh, Atman has been described as sarva-vyapi in katha, ishavasya and swetashvatara upanishads. Sarva vyapi translates as all-pervasive like the akasha and has no need to come and go, for e.g. leaving the gross body as you said because atman is spread all through out the universe. After death it is equally present in the dead gross body and also in the subtle body, but animates only the subtle body because subtle body is the reflective medium and via the subtle it makes the gross alive. But since the avaccheda people used the word embodied, its giving rise to confusion.

Comment: The word embody means, putting something inside a body. Once you put something inside an enclosed thing like water in a sealed jar, and then upon moving the jar the trapped water also moves with the jar. I think the avaccheda people used the word embodied as a metaphor, but If they literally meant, that atman being embodied also moves with the subtle body, then the upanishadic preachings on atman being sarva vyapi has no value.

Comment: Avacched vada is a theory. You can't take it so literally. Your model of subtle body travelling within the infinite field of the Atman (=Brahman in Advaita) is what is meant.

Comment: Are there any article, scripture, or video that confirms with my above sayings, coz mine too is a theory and i need to be dead sure whether my above assumption is considered as truth by majority of advaitins. Sorry for giving you trouble. Its just that im researching on these topics and i cant rely on just theories, even my own theories ;) I need verses from scriptures or legit swamis that confirms to my theory. Thank you.